# Is there any option to concatente two sql results in zend?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I having 2 database, both having same set of tables. 
I need latest three records from both db tables. Is it possible to concatenate 2 sql records in zend. because of object array concatenate is not working

I tried 'union' because of limit problem(we can give only one limit at the end of query), that not possible

Comment: If all else fails, you can combine the result set once you retrieve them. But UNION should work LIMIT can be given to individual statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [individual `LIMIT` clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) for each sub-query in the `UNION`.

From the manual:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 3);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to add clauses in zend?